# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a } f(x-a)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Proof furnished in Spivak book is falacious,and I was unable to furnish one myself,thus I ask for help here

Alternate proof from Spivaks book:

Let $g(x)=f(x-a)$ and consider $\lim\limits_{x \to a}g(x) = l$ then

$0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |g(x) - l| < \epsilon$

Now we can let $x=y+a$ (this is possible by letting $y=-|x-a|$)
Including this in the equation we get:

$0<|(y+a)-a|<\delta \implies |g(y+a)-l| = |f(y)-l| <\epsilon$ and thus it is proven

Comment: Could you explain why you think the proof in Spivak is fallacious?

Comment: Firstly it assumes that limit exists near a,secondly he defines function g(x) = f(x-a) and claims that g(y)=f(y+a)

Comment: @VanioBegic: I think there might be some misunderstanding. Can you include spivak's proof in the question?

Comment: In the end turns out not that proof is bad,but grammar,through the proof functions f and g are confused with each other,thus seeming like gibberish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: 
$$
x\in(-\delta,\delta)\iff x+a\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)
$$

that is - when $x$ in a $\delta$ neighborhood of $0$ then $x+a$
in a $\delta$ neighborhood of $a$

Edit:

We wish to prove that 
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x-a)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)
$$

Denote the above limit as $L.$

Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $\delta>0$ be such that 
$$
0<|x-0|=|x|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon
$$

which exist since $f$ have a limit at $0$.

Denote $g(x)=f(x-a)$ then we wish to prove that 
$$
\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)
$$

let $x\neq a$ be such that $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ then 
$$
|g(x)-L|=|f(x-a)-L|
$$

but $x-a\in(-\delta,\delta)$ thus 
$$
|f(x-a)-L|<\epsilon
$$

Comment: If you furnish full proof I will accept your answer,I just do not see where these hints are going.

Comment: @VanioBegic - see edit

Comment: Why did you assume function is continuous at 0?

Comment: @VanioBegic - I edited it out, I didn't use it

Comment: You still assumed that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = f(0) $ so you are still implying continuity

Comment: Does not really matter,you have lead me on right path and I thank you for that.Topic closed

Comment: @VanioBegic - right, I have made another edit, just changed $f(0)$ to some $L$

Comment: If the limit of f(x) doesn't exist at 0, then the limit of f(x-a) doesn't exist at a.

Comment: Point is the proof is here,only one more point is bothering me,that is how come that same delta works for both limits.But I am guessing that if I can get some x close to zero,then I can get x-a close to zero if I bring it close enough to a,am I rite?

Comment: @VanioBegic - that is my first hint. If $x$ is delta close to zero then shifting it by $a$ makes it delta close to $a$

Answer (score 2):

If you write down the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ formulation of a limit, then for each $\epsilon$, the same $\delta_\epsilon$ works for both. This requires a little parsing of definitions and inequalities, but not much more.

I don't have Spivak in front of me, but it seems likely to me that Spivak isn't wrong.

Also, I think that this equality is less natural then what you get when you consider $y = x + a$, and the equivalent equality

$$\lim_{y \to 0} f(y + a) = \lim_{y \to a} f(y).$$